# How to edit "kMDItemXxx" file metadata on macOS?

Tags: command-line, spotlight, metadata

Today I tried to edit the metadata of a picture file. I used `mdls` to display them, then looked for a command to edit one. But I couldn't find any.

For vanilla metadata, like basic timestamps, `touch` is good enough. And for these things called "extended attributes" (quarantine, etc.), macOS gives you `xattr -d`.

But is there a CLI way to edit, say, `kMDItemBitsPerSample` or `kMDItemFSName`, or the key/value pairs used by Spotlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spotlight system collects a variety of types of metadata about files. Some kinds of metadata are what I'd call "superficial", and can be easily changed by changing the file properties; but some "deeper" ones depend on the contents of the file, and cannot be changed without significant changes to the file itself.

`kMDItemFSName` is an example of a "superficial" attribute -- it's just the filename, so renaming the file will change it. `kMDItemBitsPerSample`, on the other hand, is a property of the data in the file (it's the bit depth of an image or audio file). Changing `kMDItemBitsPerSample` would involve some sort of recoding of the image or audio file.

Mind you, there are some attributes that are in-between in superficiality. For example, mp3 files include metadata like the album name (`kMDItemAlbum`) and track number (`kMDItemAudioTrackNumber`) that are part of the file's contents, but can be edited (by some apps, like the old iTunes) without touching the audio content of the file.

Comment: You also can use `xattr` to modify some of them. Not sure what happens if you use it to change `kMDItemFSName` though

Comment: @nohillside I tried using `xattr` to set both `kMDItemBitsPerSample` and `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemBitsPerSample` on a .tiff file, but `mdls` continues to show the original (correct for the image data) value. (`xattr -l` does show the attributes I added.)

Comment: In general, if you change a property of the file I don't think `mdls` going to reflect that until you use `mdimport` to import that specific file again to update the spotlight database.  In this case I don't think those attributes are part of the extended attributes of the file ( I don't see them in my sample files).